# Porque solo me muestra el ultimo dato recogido del bucle for?

Tags: java-swing

Tengo que crear un informe de las citas de los medicos en un text area. Por alguna razon solo me muestra el ultimo dato introducido en el arraylist de citas de dicho doctor no me muestra todo.
este es mi metodo

```
public void generarinforme() {
        int i;
        String nombre;
        int consulta;
        String doctor = "";
        String especialidad = "";
        int numConsulta = 0;
        int numCitas = 0;
        int citaNumero = 0;
        String paciente = "";
        Date fecha = null;
        String fechaS = "";
        String mensaje = "";
        mensaje += "\tInforme de Citas\n\n";
        if (cmdDoctores.getSelectedItem().toString().compareToIgnoreCase("Todas las citas") == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < listaDoctoresC.size(); i++) {
                numCitas = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getListaCitas().size();
                numConsulta = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNumConsulta();
                doctor = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNombreDoctor();
                Doctor d = (Doctor) listaDoctoresC.get(i);
                for (i = 0; i < d.getListaCitas().size(); i++) {
                    citaNumero = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getNumerocita();
                    fecha = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getHora();
                    paciente = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getPac().getNombrepac();
                }

            }
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < listaDoctoresC.size(); i++) {
                if (listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNombreDoctor().compareToIgnoreCase(cmdDoctores.getSelectedItem().toString()) == 0) {
                    especialidad = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getEspecialidad();
                    numConsulta = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getNumConsulta();
                    numCitas = listaDoctoresC.get(i).getListaCitas().size();
                    doctor = cmdDoctores.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Doctor d = listaDoctoresC.get(i);
                    for (i = 0; i < d.getListaCitas().size(); i++) {
                        citaNumero = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getNumerocita();
                        fecha = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getHora();
                        paciente = d.getListaCitas().get(i).getPac().getNombrepac();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        if (numCitas == 0) {
            mensaje += "--- Sin citas asignadas ---";
        } else {
            mensaje += "Doctor: " + doctor + "\n";
            mensaje += "Especialidad: " + especialidad + "\n";
            mensaje += "numero Consulta: " + numConsulta + "\n";
            mensaje += "numCitas\tpaciente\tfecha\n\n";
            mensaje += citaNumero + "\t" + paciente + "\t" + fecha + "\n\n";
        }
        areaInforme.setText(mensaje);
    }
```

Comment: Hola. Usas la misma variable `i` para ambos `for` y tienes que usar variables distintas. Tal vez sea mejor definir la variable en el propio for, para que pierda el ámbito cuando sales de él. De esta forma: `for( int i = 0...`. Esto te ayudará en el futuro, pero al ser bucles anidados, tendrás que definir una variable distinta para cada for.

Comment: no lo habia pensado gracias por la idea voy probar